# SecRandomCopyBytes provider (SHA1PRNG or NativePRNG) type in Objc?

Tags: ios, security, cryptography

Please can anyone clarify what type of provider (SHA1PRNG or NativePRNG) is used in SecRandomCopyBytes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

SHA1PRNG and NativePRNG are Java implementations (or stubs for) random number generators. Obviously the function in Objective C doesn't use either one.

The ["discussion" part of the documentation of SecRandomCopyBytes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1399291-secrandomcopybytes?language=objc) reads:

> This function reads from /dev/random to obtain an array of cryptographically-secure random bytes. For more information on the /dev/random random-number generator, see the manual page for random(4).

So it would be more close to `NativePRNG` on Apple configured to use `/dev/random` in all probability.

Note that the function can be configured to use different implementations:

> rng: The random number generator object to use. Specify kSecRandomDefault to use the default random number generator.

so to say that it is using any specific random number generator is already a mistake.